# Dialog widget code directly from jQuery not working?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, widget

I am currently trying to figure out why my dialog boxes are not working. I took code directly from jQuery UI and put it into my own new file too see if I could troubleshoot the problem, but the code from the website doesn't even work correctly when I copy and paste it into a new HTML file. The code in question (directly from jQuery UI):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog 
window can be moved, resized and closed with the &apos;x&apos; icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to be simple and straightforward but it is driving me crazy at the moment.  Any help fixing this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code on codepen and it works fine

But when I tried it on my computer, the css format did not appear in front of me, due to a simple reason

Focus on the following code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

As you can see, there is only // without https:, so to solve the problem, we just add this https: to the format, so the format becomes as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

The problem is solved, of course, if this is your problem, but if it is not, please explain the problem more with an example of a picture

Comment: That fixed it completely. I'm not sure why the jQuery UI website wouldn't have that in its code! Thank you very much